# How used selectors in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

When clicked from the button component, I set the `id`, then I pass this `id` into the Redux-Toolkit Query request, but `id` is initially `null`. How can I do the check?

```js
// id maybe null
const { id } = useSelector(userSelector)

const { data } = useGetUserQuery({ id });
```

Maybe props in up level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct in understanding that you really want to only make query requests for non-null `id` values then you can use a `skip` parameter or a `skipToken` to wait until `id` is non-null, or truthy.

See [Conditional Fetching](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching)

```js
const { data } = useGetUserQuery({ id }, { skip: id !== null });
```

or

```js
import { skipToken } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

...

const { data } = useGetUserQuery(id !== null ? { id } : skipToken);
```

If you don't want the query to run for *any* [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) `id` value, e.g. `null`, `undefined`, `""`, `0`, etc, then the above can be simplified a bit.

```js
const { data } = useGetUserQuery({ id }, { skip: !id });
```

or

```js
const { data } = useGetUserQuery(id ? { id } : skipToken);
```